# Is it impossible for the dimension of a topological space to increase under a smooth map?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, complex-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

First let me make a definition. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and 
$S \subset M $ a topological subspace of $M$. We say that $S$ has 
"dimenion" at most $k$ if $S$ is a subset of
$$ X_1 \cup X_2 \ldots \cup X_n  $$ 
such that each of the $X_i$ is a smooth manifold of dimension less than or 
equal to $k$. Of course $n$ is finite. Note that as per my definition 
if  $S$ has dimension at most $4$ then it also has dimension at most $5$. 
Also note that the $X_i$ need not be closed.

Suppose $\pi: E \rightarrow M $ be a compact fiber bundle over a compact 
manifold $M$ (everything is smooth). Suppose $S \subset E$ is a topological 
subspace that has dimension at most $k$. Is it true that 
$\pi(S)$ also has dimension at most $k$?

It seems to me that this should follow from the fact that there can not be 
a smooth surjective map from $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ 
if $n > m$, but I am not sure.

In case the answer is no, suppose everything was in the complex setting, 
ie $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ is a compact 
complex fiber bundle, $M$ is complex manifold, $\pi$ is a homolomorphic 
and $S$ has complex dimension at most $k$ (there is an  obvious definition 
for having complex dimension at most $k$). Is my claim true in that case, 
ie $\pi(S)$ has complex dimsnion at most $k$?

Comment: Is there some reason why you want to use this particular definition of dimension?  If you use Hausdorff dimension instead, for example, then there is a well-developed theory for this sort of thing.

Comment: My reason is the following fact: Let $V \rightarrow M$ be a rank $k+1$ vector bundle over $M$ and $X$ a smooth submanifold of $M$ of dimension $k$. Then the zero set of a generic smooth section $s: M \rightarrow V$ does not intersect $X$. Would such a statement be true if $X$ was a space with hausdorf dimension $k$?

Comment: I have heard that one can deduce this kind of thing from the results in Section 4.3.20 of "Geometric measure theory" by Federer.  However, I have never tried to work out the details myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess "smooth manifold" means "smooth submanifold".
In particular a curve which pass through a given point infinitely many times is not a smooth submanifold.

If yes then it is easy to construct an example.
Take a smooth curve $\gamma\colon(0,1)\to \mathbb R^2$ which pass through $(0,0)$ infinitely many times under different angles. Then the curve $t\mapsto (t,\gamma(t))\in\mathbb R^3$ has dimension 1 in your sense while its projection $\gamma(0,1)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension 2.

You can do the same construction in the 3-torus, so everything can be made to be compact.

Comment: I see what you are saying. What about in the complex setting (the second question I asked)? Is there still a counter example?

Comment: Yes, you can complexity the example.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Sard's theorem to $\pi$ restricted to each $S_i$; thus $\pi$ cannot increase the dimension of any $X_i$.

Comment: I am not seeing why $\pi(X_i)$ is contained inside a FINITE union of manifolds of dimension less than or equal to the dimension of $X_i$.  The image of $X_i$ need not be smooth.